# Javascript строки

Tags: javascript

Нужно в строке найти максимальное и минимальное целое число(числа могут быть отрицательными). Строка вводится с клавиатуры(там могут быть любые цифры, буквы и тд)
Меня прошлый раз удалили, т к интернет затупил и не смог ответить.

Пока я просто учусь.
Этим я просто вывел все числа.

```
Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("[-]?[0-9]+([0-9]+)?");
Matcher matcher=pat.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Как мне выделить максимум и минимум

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется вам нужно сначала определить, какой язык вы изучаете, JavaScript или всё же Java?

На JavaScript задача решается примерно так:
http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/rfxeN/

```
function getMinMax(str) {
    var numbers = str.match(/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g);
    if (numbers) {
        return {
            min: Math.min.apply(Math, numbers),
            max: Math.max.apply(Math, numbers)
        };
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```